# ¿Cómo puedo validar un edit. en Delphi 4?

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010, delphi-tokyo, delphi-berlin

Hola amigos ¿Cómo puedo validar un edit en Delphi 5 para que no me deje digitar acentos cuando pego la información  dentro del edit?

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if StrScan('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ') + chr(32)+, Key) = nil
  then Key := #0;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bienvenido a Stackoverflow(es).

Para controlar lo que necesitas (que dentro de un `TEdit` no se escriban acentos) hay 2 eventos que se suelen utilizar, cada uno con sus ventajas e inconvenientes.

Los más habituales serían: `OnKeyPress` (para controlar al pulsar las teclas) y el `OnExit`, para controlar cuando se sale del control.

- `OnKeyPress`, tiene la ventaja de que la comprobación se hace cada vez que se pulsa una tecla, es más "interactivo", pero realizas más comprobaciones. Además este evento no funciona si el texto se "pega" desde el portapapeles.
- `OnExit`, tiene la desventaja de que no se comprueba en cada pulsación del usuario, sino cuando intenta salir del control de edición. Es menos "interactivo", pero funciona bien en todos los casos.

Haz la prueba tú mismo. Coloca un formulario con 2 componentes de edición, `Edit1` y `Edit2` y coloca el siguiente código en los eventos de `OnKeyPress` y `OnExit`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
procedure TForm2.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
var
  str:string;
  i:integer;
begin
  Str := TEdit(Sender).Text;
  // recorrer los caractesdel edit
  for i := 1 to (Length(Str)) do
    if Ord(Str[i]) >200 then
      raise Exception.Create('En contenido del texto contiene un character con acentos');
end;

procedure TForm2.Edit2KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Ord(Key) > 200 then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Verás que se comportan diferente al escribir y salir. Pero en este caso sólo el `OnExit` responde bien cuando copias texto desde el portapepeles.

***NOTA:** Uso el `>200` en el código de la prueba, porque si revisas la tabla de ASCII, todos los caracteres acentuados están por encima del 200. Pero puedes cambiar esa condición o ajustarla a lo que necesites.*

Comment: @GermáEstévez Gracias me funcionó cuando digito no permite colocar tildes.

Comment: Gracias me funcionó cuando digito no permite colocar tildes y eso es lo que quería .  **pero cuando copio y pego (ctrl+c y ctrl+v) y del botón derecho del mouse si me permite pegar las vocales con tildes** ( ` á-é-í... ` )**  ¿Cómo podría hacer que no permita pegar las palabras tildes ?**  he buscado y no encuentro información. _Gracias_

Comment: ¿La duda que tengo es qué deseas hacer en ese caso? ¿Borrar todo el texto? ¿Pegar sólo la parte que no tiene acentos? ¿Pegar todo y luego eliminar las vocales con acentos?

De todas formas la opción anterior del OnExit te sigue funiocnando, porque podrás pegar el texto, pero no te dejará salir del campo.